# Access ID in Form Request when using resource route with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I'm working on a multi tenancy app and need to create some slug validation specific to the team (Laravel Spark).

My routes are set up as this for the API endpoint:

```
Route::prefix('projects/{teamId}')->group(function () {

    Route::resource('posts', 'API\PostController');

});
```

Using Axios, i'm posting to the following URL:

```
/projects/1/posts/5
```

I'm passing in the post info and there is a slug that I need to make sure is unique per team.

In my form request i'm getting the route params:

```
public function rules()
{
    $teamId = $this->route('teamId');
    $postId = $this->route('id');
}
```

The issue is, I can get the team id no problem (logging out for testing) but I cannot get the id of the resource... any ideas how to do so?

My last options is to get it from the post parameters...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the request helper to access the route like:

```
// it may be plural posts
request()->route()->parameter('post')
```

Comment: Awesome, another bit of Laravel 'magic' de-pluralising the resource name.

Comment: You'll come across that frequently with Laravel/Eloquent naming conventions. Once you get used to it though I find it to be quite intuitive.

Comment: Note 'post' is the name of the resource defined. e.g. Route::resource('post', 'PostController')